# How to fix the problem of getting error dimension too large or the File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@@environment@axis?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot `$x^{-2},x^{-4}$` and `$x^{-4}$` simulteneously using the code.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [width=2.5in,
        axis line style = thick,
        ymin=-1.5,ymax=3.5,
        xmin=-3.5,xmax=5,
        %clip=false,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick={-1,0,1,2,3},
        extra x ticks={3.14, 6.28},
        every extra x tick/.style={
            xticklabel style={anchor=north west},
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-3.5:3.5,
        samples=200,
        ]
        \addplot [domain=-3.5:3.5, thick] {(x^(-2))};
        \addplot [domain=-3.5:3.5, black, thick] {(x^(-4))};
        \addplot [domain=-3.5:3.5, black, thick] {(x^(-6))};
        \node at (axis cs:0.2, -0.22) {$O$} ;
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

When I try to run only with `$x^{-2},$` I am getting the error, dimension too large. When I try to run all the three `$x^{-2}, x^{-4}$` and `$x^{-6}.$` Then I am getting the error File ended while scanning use of `\pgfplots@@environment@axis`.

I do not know how to fix the problem because every thing seems to me correct.

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code (`\begin{document}` is missing).

Comment: @AndréC I was providing minimal code example during that I have forgotten to write \begin{document} sorry about that.

Comment: Your code is still not compilable.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code.
Indeed, you open environments or braces and do not close them.
For example, here, you begin `center` environment without ending it.
But the error you get from `pgfplots` comes from the fact that you open a brace after `every extra x tick/.style` without closing it.
Then, the dimension too large comes from the fact that the functions you are trying to compute are indeed becoming too large for `pgf` to compute when `x` is close to 0 since they tend to infinity, and you even try to make `pgf` compute 1/0 with the domain you define.

A way to avoid that would be to split your graphs in two parts, one stopping somewhere before 0 and the other starting after 0.
Another solution is to use the key `restrict y to domain` in the axis environment to filter out the `y` values when they become too large.

A functioning example with the restriction key is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \begin{axis}[%
            width = 2.5in,
            ymin = -1.5,
            xmin = -3.5,
            ymax = 3.5,
            xmax = 5,
            xtick = \empty,
            extra x ticks = {3.14, 6.28},
            xticklabel style = {%
                anchor = north east
            },
            ytick = {-1,0,1,2,3},
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            domain = -3.5:4.8,
            restrict y to domain = -1.5:5,
            samples = 200,
            axis line style = thick,
        ]
        
            \addplot [thick] {1/(x^2)};
            
            \addplot [black, thick] {1/(x^4)};
            
            \addplot [black, thick] {1/(x^6)};
            
            \node[below right] at (axis cs: 0, 0) {$O$};
            
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

As a side note, if you declare a `domain` key in the `axis` environment options, it's no use declaring it again in the `\addplot` options unless it is different.